# Autocomplete views exposed textbox for Entity reference field

Tags: 7, entities, views

I've got 2 content types "Equipment" and "Machine" , "Equipment" content type consists of an entity reference field targeting "Machine" content types.

My goal is to provide an exposed filter for user so he/she can filter equipments based on Machine's model. If "`- Enable Render Views filters as select list`" is checked in field settings exposed filter type changes to "select list" but cause I've got more than 11000 different models of machines , this is not an appropriate tool for selecting the proper model.

so the question is how can I provide an autocomplete textbox widget for this field (like what is provided in node creation form)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here : [Drupal 7 Views Autocomplete Filter | Code Karate](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-views-autocomplete-filter)

Following this solution I installed [Views Autocomplete Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) module and then in the view, I added a relationship based on field machine model and then a filter of type title of machine was provided .

Everything works great now.